# Is it proper way to return my object?

Tags: c#

This is my Class who start `Wireshark` process and return file details:

```
    public class Capinfos
    {
        private int _packets;
        private string _duration;

    private void getPackets(string file)
    {   
        ///
    }

    private void getDuration(string file)
    {   
        ///
    }

        public int packets
        {
            get { return _packets; }
        }

        public string duration
        {
            get { return _duration; }
        }

    public Capinfos getFileDetails(string file)
        {
            this.getNumberOfPackets(file);
            this.getFileDuration(file);
            return this;
        }
}
```

**MAIN**

```
        Capinfos capinfos = new Capinfos();
        Capinfos cap = capinfos.getFileDetails(file);
```

my question is regarding `getFileDetails` function, is it OK to return my object in this way ?

Comment: Why not construct new objects or change your method names to something like "PopulatePackets", "PopulateDuration", etc?

Comment: You may want to utilize *Constructor Injection* because your essentially passing a parameter, then returning the same parameter with a slight modification in detail.

Comment: Can i have an example ?

Comment: There are many ways to what you are achieving, and without knowing what exactly you're trying to eventually, its impossible to give a clear answer. But for the records, that's an acceptable practice, used in builder/fluent patterns, but your entire api should stick to it to make it more meaningful.

Comment: I suggest rename the `getNumberOfPackets()` to `ReadNumberOfPackets()` since `get` usually implies getting something from the class. The same for duration. The factory method should be `static Capinfos ReadFromFile(file)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why reference something you already have. As mentioned, you can use a constructor to pass in the information you need to 'construct' your class:

```
public class Capinfos
{
    private int _packets;
    private string _duration;

//constructor;
    public Capinfos(string file)
    {
        this.getPackets(file);
        this.getDuration(file);

    }
private int  getPackets(string file)
{   
    ///

}

private string getDuration(string file)
{   
    ///

}

    public int packets
    {
        get { return _packets; }
    }

    public string duration
    {
        get { return _duration; }
    }
```

}

Main:

`Capinfos capinfos = new Capinfos(file);`

Answer (score 2):

You could also implement the `getFilesDetails` method as a static factory method

```
public class Capinfos
{
    private int _packets;
    private string _duration;

private void getPackets(string file)
{   
    /// 
}

private void getDuration(string file)
{   
    ///
}

    public int packets
    {
        get { return _packets; }
    }

    public string duration
    {
        get { return _duration; }
    }

public static Capinfos GetFileDetails(string file)
    {
       var info = new Capinfos(file); //allowed, because it's the same class
        info.getNumberOfPackets(file);
        info.getFileDuration(file);
        return info;
    }
```

}

usage

```
var cap = Capinfos.GetFileDetails(file);
```

Comment: What benefit will give me the Static ?

Comment: this is just a way to leverage the `GetFileDetails` method, the factory pattern is mainly used if you want to leave the details of the class being instantiated up to the factory method.  Suppose you have GifFile & JpgFile both inherit from Capinfos.  By using the factory method, the class Capinfos can decide which type to create based on the file that is passed in, and the calling code would get a Capinfos object in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually take the file as a constructor. You aren't using the builder pattern like a `StringBuilder` so its strange to return the same reference.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a) create a readonly `struc` for your data, b) combine your read functions from a file

```
public struct CapInfo
{
    public readonly int Packets;
    public readonly string Duration;

    CapInfo(int packets, string duration)
    {
        this.Packets=packets;
        this.Duration=duration;
    }

    public static CapInfo ReadFileDetails(string file)
    {
        using(var fs=System.IO.File.Open(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {                
            int packets = // from the file
            string duration = // from the file

            return new CapInfo(packets, duration);
        }

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var info=CapInfo.ReadFileDetails(file);
    }
}
```